# How to get ScreenCapture with mouse pointer?

Tags: macos, mouse, screen-capture

The screen capture app on my Macbook Pro (the one that comes up when I press <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>5</kbd>) has an option to capture the mouse pointer as well. However that option doesn’t seem to work - the capture works fine, but there is no mouse pointer in the captured image.

There is some discussion [here](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/8650666), but no resolution. I’m relatively new to the Mac - is there something I’m missing, or do I need to install a third-party screen capture app?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do using Terminal. After running Terminal, run this command:

> screencapture -C -T5 Desktop/test.png

This will create a file test.png including cursor on your Desktop 5 seconds later.

Comment: This is my preferred answer, although using Preview and “entire screen” works equally well. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer to screencapture cli!

`screencapture -Cp -T 5` will make it function more like the default screen capture shortcuts (i.e. no need to specify filename / brings up window to edit after capture). 

And if you use Alfred you can create a workflow that will run this via a keyword or keyboard shortcut trigger (there's a template for it in Alfred if you've never done it before).

Answer (score 4):

You can open Preview and go to File -> Take Screenshot -> From entire screen, and the cursor will show up.

Answer (score 0):

Workarounds:

- Use tools like Highlighter or box etc in the image editing tools of preview  instead of the pointer.
- Record a small screen video and take a screenshot there.